# Ошибка Symfony 2 при работе с доктриной

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Здравствуйте, получаю ошибку:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.description AS description3 FROM Group t0':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group t0' at line 1

Работаю с Symfony 2.8, Doctrine 2.

Ошибка появляется когда объявляю переменную $repGroup;

```
 $repGroup = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Group');
 $group = $repGroup->findAll();
```

Вот описание моего класа (уже сгенерированый, но показываю без связей и сеттеров и геттеров):

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Group")
 */
class Group
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Название таблицы Group является ключевым словом sql, поэтому его нельзя использовать без экранирования. Поэтому надо либо экранировать, либо поменять название таблицы.